# Open two websites simultaneously in target frames

Tags: html, css

I want to open two URLs in different target frames by clicking on an map.
Below is required image of my page. The pages linked with map parts (1-9) are different. I have 18 external linkes for 9 map parts (1-9). So , I want to click on 1....9 map parts to open different pages. Note 1,2,3--- are not aligned and represents coordinates of map (strees/cities, etc).

By clicking on map-part(1).... it should open two pages simulateously
1-right frame, e.g., google, youtube, etc.
2-bottom frame, e.g.,google, youtube, etc.

[image]

The code should work for pc as well as mobile also. Here is my try code...
main.html

```
<html>

<frameset rows="50%,50%">
<frameset cols="50%,50%">
<frame src="inside.html" name="left">
<frame <p>Locked in a frame? <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/" target="_top">Click here!</a></p> name="right">
<frame src="bottom.htm" name="bottom" >

</frameset>
</frameset> 

</html>
```

I want to open, e.g., http://www.w3schools.com link in right frame, and another link, e.g. to Google, in the bottom frame:

inside.html

```
[![<html>
   <head>
   <title>CSS </title>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
   <style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
body {
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.image-wrap {
    width: 750px;
    height: 500px;
     padding:2px;
      background:url('pic.jpg');
}
.image-wrap a#S000 {
        display:block;
        text-indent:-10000px;
        height:500px;
        width:500px;
        position:absolute;
        left:5px;
        top:50px;
    }

   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div class="image-wrap"> <p><big>overview</big></p>   
         <a id="S000" href="http://www.w3schools.com"target="_blank">S000</a>       
   </div>
   </body>
 </html>]
```

I know one can do it by using a script, but how can I do it in my code?

Comment: `frameset`/`frame` is not supported anymore in HTML5 and you can't put a `p` tag like that inside a `frame` tag ... and I have difficult understand the question

Comment: @LGSon   see edited question for better understanding...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a start for you

*Do note that some web sites won't run in iframes for security reasons*

*Updated based on comment using an image map instead, click on the planets to load the iframes*

```js
var ais = document.querySelectorAll('.images area');
for (var i = 0; i < ais.length; i++) {
  ais[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.querySelector('iframe[name="right"]').src = e.target.dataset.nr1;
    document.querySelector('iframe[name="bottom"]').src = e.target.dataset.nr2;
  })
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  height: 50vh;
}
.left {
  width: 40vw;
}
iframe[name="right"] {
  width: 60vw;
  height: 50vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
iframe[name="bottom"] {
  height: 50vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      <span><b>Overview</b></span>
      <div class="images">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpWre.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">
        <map name="planetmap">
          <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="" href="#"
           data-nr1="http://www.w3schools.com" 
           data-nr2="http://www.apple.com">
          <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="" href="#" 
           data-nr1="http://www.w3schools.com" 
           data-nr2="http://www.apple.com">
          <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="" href="#" 
           data-nr1="http://www.w3schools.com" 
           data-nr2="http://www.apple.com">
        </map>
      </div>
    </div>
    <iframe name="right" src=""></iframe>
  </div>
  <iframe name="bottom" src=""></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: humble thank for your help (+1). But being relatively newbie , can't follow you. I don't have grid image. I have country map. clicking on map coordinates (cities, etc) should open different website. How can I stretch bottom part to fill whole screen (50% of total height). –

Comment: u r great...let me check...some web sites won't run in iframes for security reasons....u  don't mean browsers? So, I can open in all browsers...

Comment: @Shahgee: No, I mean `iframe`'s, some web site owners don't want their web site running inside an `iframe` on some else's web site, hence they can block it from doing that

Answer (score 1):

Below code works. You will have to remove the styles and use a stylesheet instead.

```
<iframe name="left_side" src="http//www.google.com" width="50%"  
        height="50%" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
<iframe name="right_side" src="http//www.google.com" width="50%"  
        height="50%" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```